# iPhone 4 circle creation on touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, drawing

How do you create filled flat circles (say white) that build out from each other in random overlap to fill the iPhone screen but ease-dissolve so that the screen never gets filled - on touch? On touch release they stop being created as they continue to ease transparency to 0 and are cleared from memory.

An example in code would be killer.

Comment: You're asking for quite a lot. What's your grounding in Cocos2d? If you're just getting started, you might be better served by a general tutorial, as opposed to opaque-to-you, specialized code.

Comment: Yea just getting started. Is cocos2d what would be used to do this? I  guess I was hoping this would be something simple (or already in a code base) for someone experienced. Pointers to tutorials would also be rock'n. Thanks Michael, I appreciate any direction I can find.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing shouldn't be too hard to do, but it would take some time to actually code. I'd be surprised but impressed if anyone were to make an example *for* you.

You could probably figure this out for yourself and learn some pretty good coding lessons on the way.

In order to do what you want, you need a pretty good handle on some concepts such as these:

```
(Cocos2d)

Touch Detection
Drawing Shapes
Random Numbers
Opacity
Timed Fade Animation (Your "Ease-Dissolve")

and utmost important:
**memory management!**
```

Comment: Thank you. The cocos2d particle effect galaxy and flower come close. Although it needs to not follow the finger on drag. I figured a 1 diminutional circle would be an easy jump leveraging that open source. Theres got to be someone out here who's done it. I hope so :)

Comment: Ah, now creating an object at a touch point is a different story as it's much less complicated than what you wanted with the circles. Using CCParticleGalaxy is very resourceful of you. Also, I'm 100% certain there is an example for that. I'm busy now but I'll see if I can find one.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you - can't wait